# Ocultar Elemento al hacer click fuera de un elemento

Tags: jquery

Tengo un formulario que está oculto, y un botón “Mostrar” que al presionarlo muestra el formulario… La idea es que cuando haga click fuera del elemento (formulario) debe ocultarse… El problema es que cuando hago click en el formulario también se oculta…

Se supone que con la negación le estoy diciendo que no oculte si presiono ciertos elementos, Pero no funciona.

```
 $("*:not(#boton_mostrar,  #frm_nuevo)").on("click", function(){ … });
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no oculte si presiono el formulario?.. Gracias de antemano.

```js
            
        $(function(){
            //oculta al hacer click fuera del elemnto (formulario)
            $("*:not(#boton_mostrar, #frm_nuevo)").on("click", function(){
            if ($("#frm_nuevo").is(":visible")){
                $("#frm_nuevo").slideUp();
            }
            });
    
            //Muestra elento (formulario)
            $("#boton_mostrar").on("click", function(event){
                $("#frm_nuevo").slideToggle();
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        
        <button id="boton_mostrar">Mostrar</button><br><br>
        
        <form id="frm_nuevo" style="display:none">
           Nombre: <input><br>
           Apellido: <input><br><br>       
        </form>
        
    </body>
```

Comment: Intenta quitar el `#boton_mostrar,`

Comment: Ya lo hice y no funciona. La idea también es que sea en diferentes elementos…

Comment: @jose7777 Ya hay dos respuestas válidas. Revísalas, a ver si te sirven.

Comment: Muchas Gracias gente… Las dos funcionan muy bien… 
Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando el evento de `document` le decimos "Si haces clic en todo el documento HTML pero, dentro del contenedor, en este caso `container` que es tu formulario, no lo ocultes, en cambio si hacemos click en todo el documento pero no detectamos el `container` oculta `container`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){
    //oculta al hacer click fuera del elemnto (formulario)
    
    $(document).on("click",function(e) {
       var container = $("#frm_nuevo");       
            if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
            //Se ha pulsado en cualquier lado fuera de los elementos contenidos en la variable container
               container.slideUp();               
            }
     });

    //Muestra elento (formulario)
    $("#boton_mostrar").on("click", function(event){
        $("#frm_nuevo").slideToggle();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});

</script>    

<button id="boton_mostrar">Mostrar</button><br><br>

<form id="frm_nuevo" style="display:none; border:solid;">
   Nombre: <input><br>
   Apellido: <input><br><br>       
</form>
```

Comment: hola @cignius use este codigo 3 botones de una pagina y en chrome funciona perfecto abriendo cada formulario pero en mozilla abre solo el primero... que puede ser?

Answer (score 1):

he encontrado una solución, utilizando el evento `mouseover` y `mouseout` para habilitar el evento `click` que ejecuta la función de muestra.

```js
            
        $(function(){
            //oculta al hacer click fuera del elemnto (formulario)
$("#contenedor").mouseover(function(e){
$("body").unbind("click");
});
$("#contenedor").mouseout(function(e){
$("body").click(function(evt){
  if ($("#frm_nuevo").is(":visible")){
      $("#frm_nuevo").slideUp();
  }
});
});
           /* $("*:not(#contenedor)").on("click", function(){
            if ($("#frm_nuevo").is(":visible")){
                $("#frm_nuevo").slideUp();
            }
            });
    */
            //Muestra elento (formulario)
            $("#boton_mostrar").on("click", function(event){
                $("#frm_nuevo").show(500);
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <div id="contenedor" style="padding:10px; border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;">  
        <button id="boton_mostrar">Mostrar</button><br><br>
        
        <form id="frm_nuevo" style="display:none">
           Nombre: <input><br>
           Apellido: <input><br><br>       
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
```